# Publish code gallery for dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to know is there any forum or google repository where we can publish our dart projects for showcasing or for fun just to exchange opinions other than github or any svn vendors as such.

Since all major platform vendors have this feature.

If yes would request someone to point me in the right direction since I am working on a small simple project and I am interested in just publishing our work just for experiment sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we have: http://www.dartlang.org/samples/. Other projects that use Google technologies are showcased on https://developers.google.com/showcase/, but Dart has its own site. http://www.dartlang.org/samples/ already has some third-party contributions. If we get a lot more, we can do more to showcase them. It'd also be great to showcase a bunch of cool apps at Google I/O, especially if they're large and in production or if they're particularly cool technologically. If you're working on those sorts of things, you can either send me email, leave me a comment, or post to the Dart mailing list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.builtwithdart.com - which aims to be a showcase of community contributed Dart apps.

To contribute pick from the following options:

1. clone, edit and submit a pull request at the site's [github](https://github.com/Dartwatch/builtwithdart.com)
2. open an issue at the site's [github](https://github.com/Dartwatch/builtwithdart.com)
3. Ping me a message

Ideally contributors would be able to provide a screenshot, a G+ link, and a paragraph or two about the app - especially welcome are any notes you have about developing it using Dart.